# Antivirus in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, antivirus

I am looking for a way to install an Antivirus in Google Kubernetes Engine(GKE). However, I could only find this [Kubernetes ClamAV tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/gcp-cos-clamav).

Here is the link of [Installing antivirus and file integrity monitoring on Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/installing-antivirus-and-file-integrity-monitoring-on-container-optimized-os).

There are two issues I am facing with this ClamAV on GKE:

1. `Ensure scan-required paths within other pods are mounted as named volumes so they will be included in the scan of the node`. This requirement in the overview suggests that only named volumes can be scanned and we want to scan almost every file inside the container.
2. Trying the steps mentioned in this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/installing-antivirus-and-file-integrity-monitoring-on-container-optimized-os) I got stuck on the step which says get all pods and `exec` into one to initiate a full scan.
    
   After creating the resources using `kubectl apply -f clamav-daemonset.yaml`
    I don't see any pods being created.

How do I solve the above-mentioned issues?

Also, is there any other alternative for Antivirus (and file integrity) on GKE apart from ClamAV?

Comment: About 1 I don't see it the same way, they just ask you to not mount it in any other way, you can't guess why.
They scan recursively the whole filesystem, except /dev /sys and /var/lib/docker 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/tutorials/gcp-cos-clamav/scan.sh

Comment: BTW it seems to scan the node filesystem, not your containers

Comment: Is there any other alternative to ClamAV?

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/10164/210